# Display single item "addr" from a JSON file in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have JSON file named `geo-where-I-will-be.json`

```json
{
    "addr": "Sorsumer Mühle, Sorsum, Hildesheim, Landkreis Hildesheim, Niedersachsen, 31139, Deutschland",
    "lat": 52.1348776,
    "lon": 9.8816979,
    "alt": 0.0,
    "raw": {
        "place_id": 156637596,
        "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright",
        "osm_type": "node",
        "osm_id": 9849814093,
        "lat": "52.1348776",
        "lon": "9.8816979",
        "class": "place",
        "type": "isolated_dwelling",
        "place_rank": 22,
        "importance": 0.2000099999999999,
        "addresstype": "isolated_dwelling",
        "name": "Sorsumer Mühle",
        "display_name": "Sorsumer Mühle, Sorsum, Hildesheim, Landkreis Hildesheim, Niedersachsen, 31139, Deutschland",
        "address": {
            "isolated_dwelling": "Sorsumer Mühle",
            "suburb": "Sorsum",
            "city": "Hildesheim",
            "county": "Landkreis Hildesheim",
            "state": "Niedersachsen",
            "ISO3166-2-lvl4": "DE-NI",
            "postcode": "31139",
            "country": "Deutschland",
            "country_code": "de"
        },
        "boundingbox": ["52.1348276", "52.1349276", "9.8816479", "9.8817479"]
    },
    "town": null,
    "county": "Landkreis Hildesheim",
    "state": "Niedersachsen",
    "country": null,
    "country_code": "de"
}
```

From this JSON I just want to display `addr` in an html file.

I found many examples which reads a JSON file with an array with many `locations`.
I tried to modify those examples. Here is my latest attempt:

```html
<table id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Suburb</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<!-- JavaScript code using jQuery -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Retrieve JSON data from "jsonexdata.json" file
    $.getJSON("dwd/geo-where-I-will-be.json", function(data) {
    var tableBody = $("#data-table tbody");

    // Iterate over each person object in the JSON data
    $.each(data, function(index, address) {
        var row = $("<tr></tr>"); // Create a new table row

        // Create table cells and fill them with the person's data
        row.append($("<td></td>").text(address.city));
        row.append($("<td></td>").text(address.suburb));
        row.append($("<td></td>").text(address.postcode));
        row.append($("<td></td>").text(address.country));

        tableBody.append(row); // Add the row to the table body
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML file displays the table headline, but does not add any rows. I expect to get just one row.

Comment: Check the syntax of the JSON. First: the JSON you sent is a single object, not an array, so when you do `$.each` it'll fail because you can't iterate over something that's not a list/array. 

Second: You're populating the rows with data that don't exist. The JSON doesn't have a `city` or `suburb` or `postcode` field, so it's undefined. The last line (after you fix the typo, it should be `address.country`, not `adress.country`) will populate because there is a `country` field, but in the example you gave it's `null`. So it'll have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your kind feedback.
I tired to pretty up the json file as there are fields for city, suburb, postcode and country.
As you probably noticed already, I am not understanding the syntax of the $.each() call. What do I have to change to remove the iteration and either read city, suburb, postcode and country OR just the single field "addr".
TIA

Answer (score 0):

`$.each()` iterates over an array but you were passing a single object instead. To make your code working as quickly as possible it's enough to keep the data as is but just dropping the loop since there's no list to iterate here.

In case you had a list of what here I called `item`s you may just iterate over such array and keep calling `addItemToTable` for each one of them.

Here in this demo the data is a statically defined object... but yet I added a commented call to `$.getJSON` that will fetch the data from a file containing that same object serialized as JSON.

```js
const data = {
    "addr": "Sorsumer Mühle, Sorsum, Hildesheim, Landkreis Hildesheim, Niedersachsen, 31139, Deutschland",
    "lat": 52.1348776,
    "lon": 9.8816979,
    "alt": 0.0,
    "raw": {
        "place_id": 156637596,
        "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright",
        "osm_type": "node",
        "osm_id": 9849814093,
        "lat": "52.1348776",
        "lon": "9.8816979",
        "class": "place",
        "type": "isolated_dwelling",
        "place_rank": 22,
        "importance": 0.2000099999999999,
        "addresstype": "isolated_dwelling",
        "name": "Sorsumer Mühle",
        "display_name": "Sorsumer Mühle, Sorsum, Hildesheim, Landkreis Hildesheim, Niedersachsen, 31139, Deutschland",
        "address": {
            "isolated_dwelling": "Sorsumer Mühle",
            "suburb": "Sorsum",
            "city": "Hildesheim",
            "county": "Landkreis Hildesheim",
            "state": "Niedersachsen",
            "ISO3166-2-lvl4": "DE-NI",
            "postcode": "31139",
            "country": "Deutschland",
            "country_code": "de"
        },
        "boundingbox": ["52.1348276", "52.1349276", "9.8816479", "9.8817479"]
    },
    "town": null,
    "county": "Landkreis Hildesheim",
    "state": "Niedersachsen",
    "country": null,
    "country_code": "de"
};

function addItemToTable(item, tableBody) {         
  var row = $("<tr></tr>");

  row.append($("<td></td>").text(item.raw.address.city));
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(item.raw.address.suburb));
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(item.raw.address.postcode));
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(item.raw.address.country));

  tableBody.append(row);
}

$(document).ready(function() {    
    const tableBody = $("#data-table tbody");
    
    addItemToTable(data, tableBody);

    // Here you can perform the same action grabbing the data object from a json file
    /*
    $.getJSON('dwd/geo-where-I-will-be.json', function(data) {
        addItemToTable(data, tableBody);
    });
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Suburb</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```